# How to deploy a Python Telegram Bot to Azure without using Flask?

Tags: python, azure, deployment, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I create a Telegram bot using Python, here is the code:

```
TOKEN = BOT TOKEN

# deploy
def run(updater):
     PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))
     updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                           port=PORT,
                           url_path=TOKEN)
     updater.bot.set_webhook("Azure WEB APP URL".format(TOKEN))


def start_handler(bot, update):
    do something

def callback_func(bot, job):
    do something

def trigger_callback(bot, update, job_queue):
    logger.info("User {} trigger bot".format(update.effective_user["id"]))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Starting!')
    job_queue.run_repeating(callback_sql, 600, context=update.message.chat_id)


def stop_callback(bot, update, job_queue):
    logger.info("User {} stop bot".format(update.effective_user["id"]))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                         text='Stoped!')
    job_queue.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("Starting bot")
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_handler))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('trigger', trigger_callback, pass_job_queue=True))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('stop', stop_callback, pass_job_queue=True))

    run(updater)
```

**I have test the Bot in local and it run perfectly. So now how can I deploy it to the Azure Cloud??? Thank guys for you helping!!!**

I see the introduction about Azure Bot Service but don't know how to do!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy:

Install [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), then create a *requirements.txt* file in the root of your python app with the libraries you need. For example:

```
python-telegram-bot>=13.3,<=13.3
```

Open Powershell or Bash, depending on your OS, and run

```
az webapp up -n <app-name> -g <rg-name> --sku <your-sku> --location <your-location>
```

A few notes:

1. Name the main file *app.py* so that Azure will run it automatically
2. Configure **Always On** on your app service in *Configuration -> General Settings*. This will always keep the bot running. Otherwise Azure will turn it off when idle and only restart it when the website is requested. As your bot works in pull mode, it will never be restared again unless you do it manually, so you need the Always On feature. You'll need a B1 or App Service Plan or better, the free plan does not support Always On.